# Dependence of Dedekind's Theorem on AC using Scott's trick

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I would like some reference about this fact: the essential dependence on choice of Dedekind's theorem in, e.g., Kelley-Morse set theory using Scott's trick.

Comment: _Which_ Dedekind's theorem?

Comment: @Lin: a set A is infinite iff A is equipotent with a proper subset of itself

Comment: What does Scott's trick have to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom of choice is needed for this proof, although strictly less than the axiom of countable choice. The axiom of foundation, however, is not needed.

The reason is that we don't define "infinite" as a particular form of cardinal. Being infinite just means **not** being finite, and being finite just means that there exist a finite ordinal which is in bijection with the set.

Being Dedekind-infinite is simply to satisfy a formula "There exists $f\subseteq X\times X$ which is an injection from $X$ into $X$ but not a surjection". Again, no reference to cardinals whatsoever. One can also use the characterization that $X$ is Dedekind-infinite if and only if there is an injection from $\omega$ into $X$, and since $\omega$ is definable by a parameter-free formula, the whole thing is again expressible. The proof of the correctness of the formula does not require the axiom of foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Actually I cannot read this book.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. currently I can not read this book. What do you mean exactly by saying *There is no use in the axiom of foundations*? 
What I would like is a discussion of cardinal and cardinality different from the classical one that relies on axiom of choice and ordinals, in fact the definition of Scott. You should take the sets of ordinals equipotent of rank minimum. I'm reading something that uses the traditional approach and makes a mention of the existence of this setting. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) I would like to see then how to obtain  Dedekind's theorem in this context, and where comes into play the axiom of choice.

Comment: Bento, but this has **nothing** to do with cardinality. Being infinite simply means not have a bijection with a finite ordinal. This can be explicitly written by a formula, so can "There exists a self-injection which is not surjective". Neither of the formulas require the axiom of foundation when we prove their correctness.

Comment: Asaf, I cite the text: *Dedekind's thm essentially depends on the axiom of choice, even under Scott's definition. Note that A "infinite" should be redefined as "there is no one-one etc..." for a definition of "infinite" not depending on the axiom of choice.* The last statement seems to me to correspond on what you've said. But the first assertion suggests that the theorem is reached in a similar way (ie, using the concept of cardinality) with the definition of Scott.

Comment: Bento, where is this cited from? And I don't see why the first statement implies that. At all. If you are willing to explain better, I'll do my best to elaborate.

Comment: Asaf, thank you for helping me. I have seen now you have changed your answer. The work is that of Monk on set theory, p. 134. I think this (the definition of Scott is not shown by Monk): With that definition we introduce a surrogate of the object/concept "cardinal", with the possibility of not using the AC or equivalent. So, I think, the discourse will be the same as in the Monk's text. Infact, he says that even using the other approach, although the cardinal is *independent* from AC, the theorem is not (implicity meaning that the definition of "infinte" in Scott is symmetric to that (...)

Comment: (...continued) in the text). I wish to see this alternative argumentation.

Comment: @Bento: It seems to me that you're confusing the fact that in $\sf ZFC$ infinite cardinals correspond to infinite initial ordinals; whereas without the axiom of choice the term cardinal is suddenly much more general. The property "infinite" and "Dedekind-infinite" are properties of sets, rather than that of cardinals. The way we define what is a cardinal has nothing to do with how we define infinite, Dedekind-infinite, or otherwise.

Comment: Asaf, yes, also in  **KM** set theory, it does so. I have looked at the definition of Scott: here we have other sets to represent the cardinality of a set, but no AC is required. Then, for the purposes of Dedekind's theorem, I guess the way is about the same as that of the text. So I ask myself where the AC appears (necessarily, following the lines of the author) in the proof. Someone can tell me?

Comment: With *Dedekind's theorem essentially depends on the axiom of choice*, the author means *in my approach*, and with  the specification: *even under Scott's definition*, he means *following the same line of definition for "infinite"*.

Comment: Asaf, *whereas without the axiom of choice the term cardinal is suddenly much more general*, yes, but the mechanism we have in mind is essentially the same, I suppose.

Comment: Please use "edit" or "delete" for your half-written comments. It's really hard to understand what you are trying to say. To the topic of the conversation let me point **again** that we don't define "infinite" as a cardinal property, but as a general property of a set. If you just want to see where the axiom of choice is needed in the proof of the equivalence then you will either have to "believe that this can't be done without it" or learn enough set theory to understand the original reference to Jech's book.

Comment: sorry but I don't have the "delete" button. The fact that it is a property of sets is clear. Also using the AC, the definition refers to a general set for infinity and correlated properties. The fact I can not read the book means that at the present time I can not have it phisically. On the net I had found the summary and I had noticed it should deal with the matter.

Comment: If you hover over your own comments there will be a little [x] button by the timestamp. I believe that there have been several threads on this site asking for proofs of this equivalence and discussion its inequivalence in $\sf ZF$. You can try and search the site.

Comment: I want to add just this. Reflecting on what Monk wrote, I have to conclude that the demonstration of equivalence using the method of Scott has to be different, since in the first case, the dependence on AC  resides only in the dependence on AC of the notion of cardinal, while in the second such dependence is lost. I imagine the proof of necessity of AC is probably difficult.

Comment: Ugh. No! There is absolutely no difference! Being Dedekind-infinite is **NOT** a cardinal property. It has nothing **whatsoever** to do with how you define cardinals. If you have the axiom of countable choice then the proof is exactly the same as it would be in $\sf ZFC$. Even if the axiom of foundation is missing.

Comment: ok .. sorry for obstinacy, but as I said the exposure of Monk's leaves the question up in the air, not providing details of the method of Scott. Also I realized that I was wrong earlier when I described this method in relation to the cardinals, but the fault is of Wikipedia under the voice "cardinal": excluding AC you can not take the sets of equipotent ordinals for an obvious reason.  Going back to what you tell me, then I have to conclude that, (continued...)

Comment: Bento, the axiom of choice appears in so many other places besides cardinals. The proof of the Dedekind theorem, the part requiring the axiom of choice is "infinite implies Dedekind-infinite", in which you essentially have to define a countably infinite subset. For this you can use the axiom of choice by choosing $n$-element subset for each $n$ and then show the union of these is countable. No cardinals.

Comment: (continued) in spite of the independence of the theorem from the notion of cardinal, the theorem, however, requires AC for its demonstration. I had followed the text of Monk, and with this approach the definition of "infinity" depends on that of the cardinal, and since this depends on AC it seemed to me that the theorem of a Dedekind-infinite set, depended in turn because of the use of the definition of departure (ie, cardinality). I must admit that  I did not look closely the proofs, for reasons of time, however, looking at them with a bit of attention now, (continued)

Comment: (continued) I do not see appear the axiom of choice except that in the concept of cardinal. What I have said, together with your observation, I think, then, that is correct. I say again, in the text I'm reading, in the proof of Dedekind's theorem, "infinite" rests on the notion of cardinal, and I do not note other applications of AC. If following Scott, this dependence on AC is maintained, not being it, however, unlike before, contained in the definition of cardinal, necessarily must manifest itself somewhere else in the proof. So it must be different from that of the book.

Comment: Thank you very much, Asaf.  What you have said seems to show the correctness of what I have just highlighted. This clarification is sufficient for me. Indeed, I was not very intersted in the proof of dependance on the axiom of choice.

Comment: One last point. The error of Wikipedia that I reported under the heading "cardinal" appears in translation in my language; the English version, however, is correct.